# RSA Encryption-Decryption of AES key and storing in file

Tags: java, file, encryption, aes, rsa

just a question if my way to do it is okay.
I made a filecrypter in java there i use a random generated AES key and encrypt files with it. The AES key will be encrypted using RSA and will also be stored in the outpufile together with the random IV.
On decryption i read the first n bytes (256byte in my case) and decrypt it with my private RSA key and then i decrypt with the AES key the rest of the file.

My main question is it okay to include the encrypted AES key in the encrypted file? It seem comfortable to me because every file i encrypt has its own random key included that was encrypted with RSA key.
Is this bad practice?

Comment: This is a simplistic summary of how, for example, PGP works. It all depends on your implementation. How are you doing to RSA encryption for example?

Comment: It's perfectly fine. It may be inefficient depending on how many files you have, how you distribute them and who the recipients are.

Comment: @BoristheSpider:     <code> KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();</code>    Its the default using padding pkcs1 i think.

Comment: Online communications generally do something very similar to this, except there the RSA is used to encrypt only the AES key and nothing else.  The AES is used to encrypt the rest, but not the IV.  The IV can be made public.  Many people will tell you that it must be kept secret, but this is not true.  Anyway, yes, it is unusual to use RSA for stored data, but there is nothing I can see insecure about it.  Editing to say there is no harm in encrypting the IV.  I just took a small tangent to say it is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @WDS: The IV won´t be encrypted - i forgot this to mention. It will be written unencrypted after the encrypted AES into the file. That means the file itself will be encrypted with AES key and the AES with RSA. The fact that the IV is random for every file i needed to store it inside the file. The new in my implementation is that i now use the asymetric way of RSA - before that i simply used AES (fixed key) and the random IV. I think its better now using RSA to encrypt AES key. One thats maybe not the best way is that i use the default instance via KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA") i think...

Comment: The usual order is to prepend the iv t the encrypted data. Then it is available immediately for decryption.

Answer (score 1):

Execution of AES is more faster than RSA  (for same key sizes).
So you can create a structure like bellow....

```
------------------------------------------------
|     |                                        |
| IV  |  Your encrypted data                   |
|     |                                        |
------------------------------------------------
```

you can store your IV with your encrypted data.
Lets say your IV is 20 size of byte[] than store it with encrypted data.
And when you want to decrypt data than first get initial 20 bytes from array than rest of data is your encrypted data.
 And you know the size of IV  .. so you can easily depart IV and encrypted data from  whole data (IV + EncryptedData).

Above is not the exact solution of your problem.
But you can surly use above one....

Comment: Dear zaph... for equal key sizes... just consider execution speed of AES-128 and RSA-4096... Does not it matter ?....

Comment: Yes exactly... so we should use RSA key for only encrypt AES keys type information and exchange between client and server.. cause increasing bit-size of RSA will come with its own cost...

Comment: What I believes is ... I have compared both algorithms on bases of same key sizes.. cause if the size is different than more size of RSA will take more time in execution ... So I have mentioned that part in my answer... And now I am expecting upvote from your side...

Comment: Lets say you have to solve a problem and you have to choose in between this AES-128, RSA-4096.... Than which one you will choose... you may need to consider execution time also.... cause no one have more time....

Comment: One chooses an asymmetric key encryption scheme (RSA or EC) if one needs a public/private key solution, symmetric key encryption (AES) otherwise. If  asymmetric key encryption is chosen and the data size exceeds the capability (see following) then a hybrid scheme is used where the data is encrypted with a symmetric key encryption and the key is encrypted with asymmetric key encryption. With RSA, the data size is limited to less than the key size. If you need asymmetric key encryption you pay the penalty, there is no choice. If possible choose symmetric key encryption

Comment: asymmetric key encryption to encrypt the symmetric keys and the data is encrypted with a symmetric key algorithm....... That i already know and i have also mentioned it in my comment also..... You just go through the comments..

Comment: By considering your suggestions.. I did required changes.... please review my answer again....